# Entity Framework Association not lazy loading for specific record. Foreign key is string

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

I have an issue that an Entity won't load an associated entity, which I believe is data specific.  It works most of the time, but I have found examples where it fails.  I have a work-around fix in SQL but I want to understand why it happens.

I'm using DB First.  This is a simplified representation of my model:

```
public class StockItem
{
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    public string CustomerCode { get; set; }

    public virtual Address Customer { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public string CustomerCode { get; set; }
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
}
```

In the SQL database, there is a foreign key on CustomerCode.  However that primary key in Address is a string, not an Integer.  Not sure if that's the issue.

Here's a very simple code snippet:

```
        int id = 1;
        StockItem stock = context.StockItems.Find(id);
        if (stock.Customer == null  && stock.CustomerCode != null) stock.Customer = context.Address.FirstOrDefault(a => a.CustomerCode == stock.CustomerCode);
```

The last line should never be needed and mostly it isn't.  However with some records, I need to add this code to retrieve the address.

I believe it's an SQL issue as I am able to fix this with an SQL query that Selects the CustomerCode from Addresses and uses that value to update CustomerCode in StockItems.  Once I've done that in the database, the code works correctly.  I did try deleting and recreating the foreign key but that didn't resolve it.

I know that would suggest that the CustomerCodes were somehow different prior to my update, but if that were the case, why did the last line above work?  Also I tested running an SQL query with a Join between the tables and that worked, so the values must have matched.

Any idea why, when the CustomerCode values in both tables match, the StockItem.Customer entity would be null but could be retrieved when using StockItem.CustomerCode as the key value to directly retrieve from the Address table.

Finally, thinking about it, I'm not sure it's specifically a lazy loading issue as I also tried using an .include("Address") when retrieving StockItem and it made no difference.

---

*** EDIT ***

I found it.  The CustomerCode value in the Address table had been amended from "Customer Uk" to "Customer UK" (capital K).  Update cascade is off due to conflicts with other Foreign Keys.  So the SQL join and the EF Select is Case Insensitive, while the EF association loading must be case sensitive.

Is there any way of overriding that in EF?

Comment: There's not enough information about your model to speculate.  You'll need to at least post the table definitions and the entity definitions and the relationship configuration.

Comment: If you found specific examples that don't work try comparing their `DATALENGTH(CustomerCode)` results - possibly they have differing amounts of trailing spaces or other control characters.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Thanks, I didn't as I was trying to provide a simple example and as I believe those definitions would appear correct as it does work over 99% of the time.  It does appear data related.  Could there be any other reason, such as a non-printing character in one of the key values that is picked up by EF but doesn't affect the SQL.  Or if the key value in the Address table is amended, and there is no update cascade set, could that break the EF link, even if SQL referential integrity is entact?

Comment: The likely root cause is that the foreign key property in EF is not configured correctly.  So I'm hesitant to speculate on more exotic problems until that's verified.

Comment: Found it (see edit in original post). The EF association is case sensitive, while the SQL Join is not (apparently).

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft I guess you could say that the foreign key property was the issue as it did not cascade on Update, but that is because in the production DB, that table has multiple foreign key links to the address table (and others) and - I think - SQL generates a conflict if you cascade on multiple keys, so preventing it.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: I would strongly recommend to NOT use strings as FKs, if you have any chance of changing that now.

Comment: @Mafii - I understand and agree.  It's a legacy issue that's not straight-forward to resolve.

Comment: @JonRoberts that is the pain of working with software, indeed. I assumed so reading your post.